# Tornadofx runAsync issue

Tags: javafx-8, tornadofx

```
runAsync {} ui {}
```

The ui{ } block is triggered sometimes and sometimes not . What causing it . 
From my understanding if the task in runAsync { } is a quick task then ui{} doesn't work . Please help. It's kind of frustrating.

Comment: This is actually a design flaw of `runasync`, one that we ran into while just doing a println or similar inside the work block. I've never seen it bite anyone while doing actual work though, and since we haven't found a nice solution to it, we've let it be. Can you tell me what you're doing that executes so fast that this fails? The alternative would be to create a JavaFX `Task` manually and attach a success callback to it. I'd like to investigate this further and find a permanent solution.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Actually this issue makes the program in a unstable state . That is unpredictable. I was trying to get a observablelist from controller which is I think a normal use case . Then I was doing items = it inside ui block for a tableview . As  ui block fails to execute the table view was not showing any data .

Comment: Can you add a fail{} function to your block?  This way, we can rule out an application exception.  ui{} is not guaranteed to be called if an exception is thrown in the runAsync{} block.  runAsync{ ... } ui { ... } fail { ... }

Comment: I did try to do that but surprisingly. The fail {} block is not involved either . I think because it didn't failed . It was just fast .

Comment: As per my understanding this runasync {} ui {} and asynchItems {} need some work .

Comment: @EdvinSyse have you tried using a `CountDownLatch`, or some other concurrency primitive for controlling this?

Comment: The problem was with earlier implementation where `ui` is just an extension function on Task, which is attached after the task is created and the operation has begun. The problem has now been resolved though.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a design flaw in the `ui` function. It simply attached the passed in function to the s`etOnSucceeded` callback without checking if the task was already complete at this point. This has been corrected in `tornadofx-1.7.14-SNAPSHOT`, which is available in oss.sonatype.org now. See the [README page](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx) for information about how to use snapshot releases :)

Comment: Yes it does, since `asyncItems` is chaining task -> success.

Comment: after version 1.7.14 . still table view does not update on addition of new item in the backed observable list. Where as this works: val task = task { controller.getServices() }
                task.setOnSucceeded { items = task.value }

Comment: why this issue still persist ?

Comment: The issue you reported is fixed. If you're experiencing issues now, please file an issue at GitHub including steps to reproduce.